# ImportError: cannot import name 'Usuario' from 'usuarios.models

Tags: django

Tenho esses modelos onde o condomínio pode ter vários apartamentos e um apartamento pode ter vários proprietários, cada condomínio tem um síndico, subsindico e um gerente. Estou adicionando sindico, subsindico e gerente na classe condomínio, entretanto, ao executar o makemigrations, eu tenho o seguinte erro:

```
from usuarios.models import Usuario
ImportError: cannot import name 'Usuario' from 'usuarios.models
```

**Classes Condomínio e Apartamento**

```
from django.db import models
from endereco.models import Endereco
from usuarios.models import Usuario

class Condominio(models.Model):
   nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
   endereco = models.ForeignKey(Endereco, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   sindico = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   subsindico = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   gerente = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


   class Meta:
       db_table = 'condominio'
       verbose_name = 'Condomínio'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Condomínios'

   def __str__(self):
       return self.nome


class Apartamento(models.Model):
   numero = models.CharField(max_length=8)
   condominio = models.ForeignKey('Condominio', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   class Meta:
       db_table = 'apartamento'
       verbose_name = 'Apartamento'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Apartamentos'

   def __str__(self):
       return self.numero
```

**Classes Usuário e PerfilUsuario**

```
  class Usuario(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
     perfil_usuario = models.OneToOneField('PerfilUsuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
     sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEXO)
     data_nascimento = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
     cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    telefone1 = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=False, blank=False)
    telefone2 = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=False, blank=False)
    apartamento = models.ForeignKey(Apartamento, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    proprietario = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['nome']

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'usuario'
       verbose_name = 'Usuário'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Usuários'

   @property
   def get_primeiro_nome(self):
       return self.nome.split(' ')[0]

   def salvar(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(Usuario, self).save()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.nome


class PerfilUsuario(models.Model):
    tipo_usuario = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TIPO_USUARIO, verbose_name='Tipo de Usuário')
    desabilitado = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'perfil_usuario'
        verbose_name = 'Perfil do Usuário'

   @property
   def get_usuario(self):
       return self._usuario.nome

   def __str__(self):
       return self.tipo_usuario

TIPO_USUARIO = [
    ('S', 'Síndico'),
    ('SS', 'Subsíndico'),
    ('G', 'Gerente'),
    ('M', 'Morador'),
]
```

**Stacktrace completo**

[Link para o Stacktrace completo](https://pastebin.com/QJRLRBdC)

[EDIT]

Em outros diretórios o import ocorre normalmente, mas nesse específico, não

**Exemplo onde o import está ocorrendo normalmente**

```
from django.db import models
from usuarios.models import Usuario
from choices.tipo_aviso import TIPO_AVISO


class Aviso(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipo_aviso = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TIPO_AVISO, verbose_name='Tipos de Aviso')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'aviso'
        verbose_name = 'Aviso'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Avisos'

    def __str__(self):
         return self.descricao
```

Comment: vc tem certeza que existe `Usuario` em `usuarios.models`?

Comment: Sim, existe, inclusive em outros models de outras apps do projeto eu consigo importar o usuário normalmente, entretanto, nesse específico, não

Comment: A partir de que deretorio vc esta fazendo o import? Esta me parecendo que o problema esta no "caminho" da importação, por exemplo, se vc estiver no mesmo diretorio usuarios, deveria fazer `from .models import usuario`

Comment: As classes Condominio e Apartamento, estão em um diretório e Usuario e PerfilUsuario estão em outro diretório

Comment: estranho, sabemos que é um erro de caminho, provavelmente algum erro de escrita, verifique se os nomes combinam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apague o trecho `from usuarios.models import Usuario` e faça o seguinte:

```
usuario = models.ForeignKey('usuarios.Usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

O mesmo é valido para todos os trechos onde você quer adicionar o relacionamento, apague o import e referencie a class como citado acima.

Comment: Isso resolve pra mim,  obrigada